# How to sort by the column associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do have these tables

`users` and `profiles`
User has one profile.

There is a column called `point` in `profiles` table.

I'd like to fetch all the users sorted by the `point`.
How can I customize this controller??

**controller**

```
@users = User.confirmed.page(params[:page]).order("point DESC")
```

**model**

```
scope :confirmed, where("confirmation_token" => nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to join if you want to sort on the column using sql

```
@users = User.confirmed
  .page(params[:page])
  .order("point DESC")
  .joins(:profile)
```